# Alternatives to AWS Amplify DataStore with offline capabilities for GraphQL

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify, offline, offline-caching

I've developed a project using AWS Amplify and DataStore. It was a requirement that the app works offline, because most of my users are travelling in areas with poor or no signal. DataStore seemed like a perfect solution, but it has given me far too many problems. Performance is awful when dealing with more than a few hundred records and I'm getting many complaints from users about data just not syncing at all even when there is signal.

Unfortunately these problems have only really manifested after going into production, and it has a really big dependence on DataStore (1800+ references to "DataStore" in the code, most are in tests to be fair).

I want to try and swap it out for something else, but I don't know what to go with. It's going to be a lot of work and I only work on this project as a volunteer, so I'm really keen to get it right this time (this would actually be the third time I do a swap, I went from REST and redux-saga before, but the project was smaller then).

Are there any good offline first or at least offline capable solutions that will work with GraphQL? I'd like to go with something like Apollo, but I'm worried that I'm going to get even more complaints because if it doesn't properly work in poor or no signal areas, then the app is going to be even more useless most of the time.

As an aside has anyone used DataStore in a project and not had such a bad experience? Sometimes I wonder if I'm just doing something wrong, but I haven't been able to pinpoint exactly what is happening. To some extent the slowness can be remedied with sync expressions and clearing the database occasionally, but the data not syncing (both in and out) is really frustrating.

Thanks.